# jquery -this-show and hide for tooltip

Tags: jquery

I have 3 to 4 buttons and when I click on 1st button –a popover –tooltip is opening & click on 2nd button tooltip is opening but the 1st button tooltip is not closing.
I want close the tooltip popover when I click on the next button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn).click(function() {
        $(this).find('.popover).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide all `popover` elements before showing the targeted one, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        //Hide All
        $('.btn .popover').hide();
        //Show Target
        $(this).find('.popover').show();
    });
});
```

---

<sub>**Note::** You are missing some close `'` elements on your selectors check that</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check [jQuery siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

Something like 
`$(this).siblings().find('.popover').hide();`

right after your 
`$(this).find('.popover').show();`

should do the job.

Also check typos like 
`('.popover)` should be `('.popover')`

Simple example
https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/6hj7p94g/